# Python REPLACE into Azure SQL database

Tags: python, sql, replace, azure-sql-database

I am working on a way to update our Azure database automatically.
My first version was with the INSERT command, but now I want a more reliable SELECT REPLACE command.
The following line:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT REPLACE INTO [dbo].[PPC_TPEX_TEST]([Enter],[Leave],[StartTime],[EndTime],[Area], [Camera]) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                    row['entry'], row['exit'], row['Start'], row['End'], row['Area'], row['Camera'])
```

Only the following error occurs:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT REPLACE INTO [dbo].[PPC_TPEX_TEST]([Enter],[Leave],[StartTime],[EndTime],[Area], [Camera]) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Enter'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` is a MySQL syntax. Are you using MySQL or MSSQL? Even for MySQL the syntax should be `REPLACE INTO`, not `SELECT REPLACE INTO`!

Comment: I am using the SQL database in the Azure envoirement. REPLACE INTO gives me a lot of errors, would you mind write the whole query? maybe i see where i go wrong.
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment above, you appear to be using [Azure SQL database](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/sql-database/) which is based on Microsoft SQL Server ([T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-reference) standard). T-SQL does not have any `REPLACE INTO` like [MySQL](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html). You can use [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) instead, to serve the same purpose as REPLACE.

A common scenario is updating one or more columns in a table if a matching row exists. Or, inserting the data as a new row if a matching row doesn't exist.

Example (use table and column as per your scenario):

```
MERGE dbo.Table1 AS target  
    USING (SELECT @id, @Name) AS source (Id, Name)  
    ON (target.Id= source.Id)  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET Name = source.Name  
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
        INSERT (Id, Name)  
        VALUES (source.Id, source.Name)
```

And if you want to use MySQL specifically, that is also available as a different service in Azure. https://azure.microsoft.com/services/mysql/